# Is there some trick to replace rebooting in windows?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

I've added the directory of `php.exe` to `PATH` variable,and it's available for `administrator`,but it's not available for user `daemon`.

But it's available after rebooting,why is rebooting necessary?Is there some trick to replace rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Changes to environment variables should be seen immediately by any **new processes**.  Existing processes that are already running will continue to have their existing environment until they are restarted.

You should also make sure you were updating the system variables and not the user-specific variables for the administrator account.